# Create view for two tables that have similar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have 2 tables.

- `tableOne` has columns `Id, SN, SyN, SSN, APU`

Here are 3 example rows:

```
Id   SN    SyN   SSN   APU
----------------------------
'1'  'a'   'a'   'a'   'a'
'2'  'b'   'b'   'b'   'b'
'3'  'c'   'c'   'c'   'c'
```

- `tableTwo` has columns `Id, Uri, MAM`

Sample data:

```
Id      Uri     MAM
--------------------
'4'     'aa'    'aa'
'5'     'bb'    'bb'
```

I'm trying to create a view that will use the Id columns into one column and have a view like so:

Header:

```
Id | SN   | SyN  | SSN  | APU  | Uri  | MAM
--------------------------------------------
1  | a    | a    | a    | a    | null | null
2  | b    | b    | b    | b    | null | null
3  | c    | c    | c    | c    | null | null
4  | null | null | null | null | aa   | aa
5  | null | null | null | null | bb   | bb
```

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM CIR.BusinessApplication AS BA
FULL OUTER JOIN CIR.NetworkAddressableDevice AS NAD
ON BA.Id = NAD.Id
```

If the code is run, it basically places the two tables side by side. I also tried "CREATE VIEW CIR_REPORT AS" and the code and I was receiving a few errors.

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to create a view with `SELECT *` since the tables both have a field named `ID`, you can use `COALESCE()` for the `ID` field since both aren't always populated, then just list out the other fields:

```
SELECT COALESCE(BA.ID,NAD.ID) AS ID
      ,SN ,SyN ,SSN ,APU ,Uri ,MAM
FROM CIR.BusinessApplication AS BA
FULL OUTER JOIN CIR.NetworkAddressableDevice AS NAD
  ON BA.Id = NAD.Id
```

That's the only error that jumps out, if there are others please add them to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define your `select` better.

```
SELECT ISNULL(BA.Id, NAD.Id) as ID, SN, SyN, SSN, APU, Uri, MAM
```